# Bootstrap 3.1 input-group inline with auto width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I do not understand the following thing.
In the first left floating div i have a few buttons, and in the secound left floating div is a input-group.
The input-group moves one line down but it should use the free space.

http://www.bootply.com/f1MbCrF1w5

The secound method is used a fixed width, but it should use the free space, the first div should it make like "wrap content".
Is it possible and how can I solve it?

Thanks!

sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/22kf1Yt3U4)***

You need to use `display: inline` for the `btn-group` class and disable `float: left` for it if you want to display buttons in one lane with the input element.

I assume you only want it to work for one element and not affecting other elements with `btn-group` class, so I created the `exception` class to select only one `btn-group`

If no and you want it to select all the `btn-group` items, then delete my `exception` class. But I got no idea what's your architecture is going to be and this global `display: inline` for `btn-group` can sometimes lead to unpredictable display.

Anyways, my last 2 paragraphs are not related to the issue but to the selectors structure and system.